# JasperReports: Error show image(BLOB) in report using SQLITE

Tags: java, sqlite, jasper-reports, blob

I need to visualize a image blob in report, using sqlte. I can show this image in class java 
through ImageIcon in a label.

I already tried modify the type field for `java.io.ImputStream,` but unsuccessfully.

what else can I do?

```
<field name="qst_imagem" class="java.io.InputStream"/> 
<image onErrorType="Blank"> 
<reportElement uuid="15dbc118-3058-4335-a3b4-5bc0075bb9c6" x="0" ="0" width="100" height="43"/> 
<imageExpression><![CDATA[read($F{qst_imagem})]]></imageExpression> 
</image>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you provide some sample code for us to review, which would enable us to help you better?

Comment: Yes, Derek. This code is in the xml of ireport.
`<field name="qst_imagem" class="java.io.InputStream"/>
<image onErrorType="Blank">
<reportElement uuid="15dbc118-3058-4335-a3b4-5bc0075bb9c6" x="0" ="0" width="100" height="43"/>
<imageExpression><![CDATA[read($F{qst_imagem})]]></imageExpression>
</image>`

Comment: Please edit your question to include that XML sample, since not everyone will read through the comments on a question before moving on to another question. Thanks!